# rspec title test is failing, I am setting the title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My rspec title test is failing with:

```
1) HomeController Get 'index should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",
     expected following output to contain a <title>TitleTest</title> tag:
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
     # ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:13
```

My homecontroller has:

def index()
    @title = "TitleTest"
  end

my view (application.html.erb) has:

```
<title><%= @title %></title>
```

Running rails server shows that my title does get set, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in your controller spec, you have it set to `render_views`. Otherwise, rspec will not have the view to look into. Just add that bit of code right after your describe controller block.

Update: You can find an example right [here](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/dir/controller-specs/render-views)

Answer (score 1):

'render_views' is definitely needed. I also ran into a similar situation and my problem was that I did not retrieve the page before executing the expectation. In other words, the structure should be:

```
describe... 

 it...  # previous expectation

 it...
   get 'mypage' 
   response should...
```

I was wrongly assuming that I did not need to **get 'mypage'** and that I could reuse the response from a previous expectation